# Why can't my forensics live cd mount windows share

Tags: forensics

I am having a rather aggravating issue. I want to output Dcfldd to a Windows share on another machine but I cannot mount the share, I have tried on Backtrack and Sans SIFT both in forensics mode and regular mode.

```
Using the GUI I went to Connect to -> Windows share
Server => 192.168.1.3
Share => Forensics
Username => admin
domain name => WORKGROUP
```

It asks me to enter my password and then I get

it returns cannot display location, failed to mount Windows share.

I can ping the machine. This happens even when running live CD in regular mode.

Any idea why both CDs give the same result?

Comment: Cant think why this question is on Security.se

Comment: The issue is only with Forensics Live CD, I do not have the issue with any regular Linux OS